# How do I group senders in Lotus Notes 8.5?

Tags: lotus-notes

Is it possible to group by sender in your inbox? I spend too much time looking for specific mail from individuals. I would like to be able to collapse all the incoming mail from 1 person then expand it again when new mail arrives.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is sorting by thread.  Try checking to see if you have an option that allows your messages to be grouped in threads.  Hope this helps